# Is it possible to display numeric keyboard for Messenger Platform?

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

I am developing a bot using the Messenger Platform with Node.js. Sometimes the user need to provide an information based only on numbers. Is there a way to display the numeric keyboard in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying the keyboard type is not supported.